# Store variable to disk so I can access it when a process is run next time

Tags: bash, unix

I have a process running as a cron job and I want it to access a variable which stores information when a certain action(delete action on db tables, performed by the same job in a previous run) has last been performed. I know I can write the timestamp to a file, but is there a easier way?, I believe environment variables loose context when the shell session ends, I want the process to see the value when the session restarts.

Answer (score 2):

You have to store your data in files, using environment variables, even if you do EXPORT yourvar, your variable and it's data will be available in that session, if you restart your computer it will be lost. You can store that environment variable value in bashrc file, but at all you have to use a file.